# Create Poll in C# (windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, charts

I want create a poll. i have a table for questions(Fields: ID,Question) and another for answers(Fields: ID,QuestionID,Answer). There is a table for the results(fields: QuestionID,AnswerID,UserID).i want to show the Percent of responding to any item in datagridview.
for example when i enter question id, datagridview show:

### Choose question ID:1

### Option...........Percent

1 -------------------------       30

2 -------------------------- 20

3---------------------------50

4-------------------------- 10

this is my code But the result does not show it:

```
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        var q = (from s in Session.DB.PoolUsers
                 where s.PoolQID == a
                 select s);
        var qq = (from c in q
                  group c by c.PoolAID into agroups
                  select agroups.Key);
        var qqq = (from c in qq
                   select c).Count();
        MessageBox.Show(qqq.ToString());
```

And there is my classes:

```
    public partial class PoolA    //For answers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string QuestionID { get; set; }
}

     public partial class PoolQ    //Questions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string AnswerID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
}

     public partial class PoolUser  //resaults
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PoolQID { get; set; }
    public int PoolAID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you publish the relevant entities(classes) ?

Comment: what do you mean by results does not show it? how can you see the percentages in the gridview and not the code; what is the intended outcome of the linq you have published? Just overall need more information

Comment: @MutuYolbulan i show the resault manually just for example, code show me just "2" in a message box

Comment: @oreleraki here is my entities,edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the optimal way I would do it, I would highly consider you, to change your entities.

**Here is the solution:**

```
int questionId = 1;
var questionAnswers = list.Where(elem => elem.PoolQID == questionId);
int questionAnswersCount = questionAnswers.Count();
var answersPrecentage = questionAnswers
                        .GroupBy(elem => elem.PoolAID)
                        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => (grp.Count() * 100.0 / questionAnswersCount));
```

[.NET Fiddle Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i8OFfd)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your intentions but I think you should redesign the schema (not that it not doable as it is) for maximum efficiency. You call your PoolUser table your results table but it is your answers log at best. you need a table that has the results processed already such as would be done in a DWH kind of situation.

If you have a results summary table you could work out vertical sums groups all day without the extra performance of joining tables etc. for ad hoc data. I reckon you'd be running this a lot to go over the results, so it sounds like it is a better idea to store the summarized information for reporting, performance etc.

as for the current state of the problem:

```
var qq = (from c in q
          group c by c.PoolAID into agroups
          select agroups.Key);
```

agroups has the answerIds grouped up for the question number you typed in.
then you are just showing the row count of the grouped up answers which shows you 2:

```
var qqq = (from c in qq
           select c).Count();
```

you are telling me that your messagebox shows the number "2"
this means that people only selected 2 options to answer whatever question id you put in. you don't know whether the answer is correct or not. the last query "qqq" you have, you have the count outside so it only returns the row count. you don't want the row count. you want the answerID count after the grouping.

```
from c in qq
select count(c)
```

this is the total answers for the questionID you typed in.

now you need the correct answers in order to calculate the percentage. this is the query missing. you have gone 75% of the way. just finish it off. hopefully this is sufficient detail and not too much text to read.

Comment: thanks, usefull... PoolUser is my answers log.  but i dont know exactly how can i calcuate the percentage of every answer for a question... I wanted to  count Members who voted for each option and then calculate the percentage of them. This is true? How can I do this? according to that the number of options is unlimited...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved and I got the following code. I also draw a graph based on

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = (from c in Session.DB.PoolUsers
                 select c).ToList();
        int questionId = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        var questionAnswers = list.Where(elem => elem.PoolQID == questionId);
        int questionAnswersCount = questionAnswers.Count();
        var answersPrecentage = questionAnswers
                                .GroupBy(elem => elem.PoolAID)
                                .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => (grp.Count() * 100.0 / questionAnswersCount));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = answersPrecentage.ToArray();


        //Draw Chart From DataGridview:
        chart1.DataBindTable(answersPrecentage);

    }
```

And works properly
Thanks all :)